# Laravel many-to-many relationship with multiple custom pivot tables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I hope I'm not asking an already answered question, but using all the search terms I can think of I can't work out a solution to this:

I have two tables, `companies` and `respondents`

Sometimes, a respondent can **select** one or more companies. A company can be **selected** by one or more respondents.

Other times, a respondent can **rate** one or more companies. A company can be **rated** by one or more respondent.

It is possible for a respondent to both **select** and **rate** a company. (Indeed, all companies that a respondent rates they have to have selected, but they don't rate all the companies they select).

As a further complication, a respondent is an **employee** of one company only, and is also **nominated** by one or more companies to to the selecting and rating.

My line of thinking is to have multiple custom pivots:

```
//relationship between 'companies' and 'respondents' to show who they selected 
selected_companies 

//relationship between 'companies' and 'respondents' to show who they rated 
rated_companies 

//relationship between 'companies' and 'respondents' to show which companies a respondent was nominated by 
nominating_companies

//relationship between 'companies' and 'respondents' to show who a respondent is employed by
employment
```

I guess the last one is a simple one to many, so I can just put a custom named FK of `employer_id` in the `respondents` table.

Other than that, I'm pretty stuck as to how to implement this. I know that custom intermediate pivot models is a thing, but I also can't figure out how to implement that.

Comment: It may not solve your issue directly but explore Custom Ploymorphic Many to Many Relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types, atleast using this you do not need to define multiple intermediate pivot tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so here's how I dealt with this.

#### Custom pivot table

In the pivot, I added a column called `type`. This is what my `company_respondent` pivot table migration now looks like:

```
    Schema::create('company_respondent', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('company_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('respondent_id');
        $table->string('type');

        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('respondent_id')->references('id')->on('respondents')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['company_id','respondent_id','type']);
    });
```

Note that for the primary key I am using all three columns. This will allow me to declare different types of relationship between the same company-respondent pair, e.g. when the respondent has selected a company I can store `selected` and when they have rated a company I can store `rated` in the `type` column.

#### withPivot

Before I can do this, I need to tell Laravel to expect this new column in the `Company` and `Respondent` Models using `withPivot()` when defining the relationship. I need to do this on both sides of the relationship:

```
//Respondent.php

    use App\Company;

    public function companies() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)->withPivot('type');
    }


//Company.php

    use App\Respondent;

    public function respondents() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Respondent::class)->withPivot('type');
    }
```

That done, I can now store into that column when saving a relationship, and filter using it.

#### Storing:

```
$respondent->companies()->attach($companies_selected, ['type'=> 'selected']);
```

Where `$companies_selected` is either a single id or an array of ids.

#### Filtering:

```
//returns an array of company names that a respondent with an id of `2` has selected.

$company_names = Respondent::find(2)
                    ->companies()
                    ->wherePivot('type','selected')
                    ->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

I can simply substitute `selected`, `rated`, `nominated` or anything else that I like to define the different types of relationships that can exist between the two tables.

I hope this helps someone else, or I get feedback on a better way to do this.