# get data in laravel many to many relationship with two pivot tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

i have two pivot tables based on three models- user, client and location

location_user-
user_id
location_id

client_location-
client_id
location_id

i want to get clients according to locations defined by user.i have defined the relationship as belongs To Many.how can i achieve it.thanks

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Doesnt `User::with('locations.clients)` work for you? This should give you Users with locations along with clients associated with that location. That is assuming you have `clients` relationship in Location model..

Comment: [You can use withPivot for this, this has been already answered, please refer the thread below.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704158/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-with-multiple-custom-pivot-tables)